# Safe operating temperature for power inductor

Tags: inductor, heat

I'm currently developing a DC-DC buck converter that has a rated output of 10A/60V. When the average output current is 7.5 amps, my main inductor heats up to about 40°C (room temp's about 25°C). I made the inductor myself, with a T300 red ferrite core (OD = 7.2 cm, ID = 4.9 cm, t = 1.27 cm), and a permeability factor of 10. For the wire, I'm using a 2 mm enameled copper wire. I did around 220 turns to get 600 µH. You can see the inductor in the picture below.

[image]

My question would be, how hot can the inductor get before it causes problems in my circuit? Does operating the inductor in 40°C safe? If not, how would you recommend me lowering the wire temperature?

Comment: I don't have a hard number but 40C is fine. That's not even too hot to touch. Even magnets don't demagnetize there. Beyond 50-60C which is too hot to touch is when you possibly start running into problems but a lot of electrical and electronic components also run fine at those temperatures, especially things that aren't semiconductors, magnets notwithstanding.

Comment: Yes, it's only warm to the touch, and I decided not to test the circuit for higher output current. My main concern is about the inductor properties changing due to the temperature rise. Should I be worried about that?

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about properties changing for an inductor at least.

Comment: You should look for the safe operating temperature of the wire insulation.

Comment: What about the datasheet of the inductor core? Is there any information about temperature and its influence to permeability?

Comment: Insulation-dependent.  For example Kapton is awesome vs temp, but also doesn't last since it gets beat up via thermal expansion of copper within, and causes a huge mess when it does fail... on the other end, some easy to use enamel stuff will burn or melt from a soldering iron..

Comment: @Uwe unfortunately, I got the wire from a generic store, and I doubt they have the datasheet for the wire. Same thing with the inductor, there's no datasheet available, only the dimension, the permeability constant, and a material type (It says that the material is a "2").

Comment: @Abel my wire is a generic enameled wire that doesn't come with a datasheet or some sort. Is there any rule of thumb for this sort of thing?

Comment: Search for an enameled wire with a datasheet, a wire looking very similar to the wire you used. Look if there are different wires isolations with different maximum temperatures. Choose the smallest one you found.

Comment: Here is useful information about thermal properties of enameled wire : https://www.maier-kupferdraht.de/kupferlackdraht/80-produktdetails-kupferlackdraehte  note the page is in German, when using English keywords for search I found only this wire from Hong Kong https://www.hoiluen.com/sites/default/files/users/linda/e257525.pdf with much lower temperatures.

Comment: @Uwe thanks for the pointers, I'm probably going to use the Hong Kong wire specs as reference just to be safe